# Client-generated JSON to be stored in MongoDB serverside, application/json not parsing correctly?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I'll be brief; I have a [client-side form](http://goo.gl/KFco05) that allows for creation of "quizzes", a series of questions with answers attached to them, to be sent off to the server to be stored to a MongoDB. I've tried to do this in in accordance with [W3's specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/), but the promised results are not matching the results I'm getting.

I want my JSON to consist of nested objects, like so:

```
{
    "_id": "54a884c68999af900fc28dcb",
    "name": "testquiz",
    "author": "user",
    "questions": [
        {
            "text": "question one",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "text": "answer one",
                    "correct": false
                },
                {
                    "text": "answer two",
                    "correct": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "question two",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "text": "answer one",
                    "correct": true
                },
                {
                    "text": "answer two",
                    "correct": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I can only be able to get results like these:

```
 {
    "_id": "54a8b00108039068102f8835",
    "quizname": "World War II",
    "questions[0][text]": "When did WWII start?",
    "questions[0][answers][0][text]": "1938",
    "questions[0][answers][1][iscorrect]": "on",
    "questions[0][answers][1][text]": "1939",
    "questions[0][answers][2][text]": "1944",
    "questions[0][answers][3][text]": "1914",
    "questions[1][text]": "",
    "questions[1][answers][0][text]": "",
    "questions[1][answers][1][text]": "",
    "author": "user"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm quite a newbie to the MEAN stack, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It took me an embarrassing amount of time and a gut-wrenching amount of searching, but it works.

```
    $('#savequiz').click(function () {
        obj = {
            quizname: $('#quizname').val(),
            author: "",
            questions: []
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < questionCount; i++) {
            obj.questions.push({
                text: $('#question_' + i).val(),
                answers: []
            });

            for (var j = 0; j < answerCount[i]; j++) {
                obj.questions[i].answers.push({
                    text: $('#question_' + i + '_answer_' + j + ' > div > input').val(),
                    correct: $('#question_' + i + '_answer_' + j + ' > div > span > input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')
                });
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/quiz/new',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        });

        return false;
    });
```

I believe the solution manifests itself in the $.ajax call parameter  `'processData: false'`
This still doesn't answer my curiosity regarding why W3's spec on form submission with `application/json` didn't work to spec, but at least I got it to work, and am posting this, hoping it'll help if anybody else encounters the same problem. It's been a while since I encountered something so seemingly simple which proved so time-consuming.

In case it's of any relevance or interest, this is how I process the request:

```
app.post('/quiz/new', function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.loggedin) {
      res.status(401).end();
      return;
    }

    var quiz = req.body;
    quiz.author = req.session.username;

    db.collection('quiz', function (err, collection) {
      collection.insert(quiz, {safe: true}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to persist quiz!');
            res.send({'error': 'An error has occurred'});
            return;
        }

        console.log("Successfully persisted quiz.");
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```